How to turn a serial for loop into a parallel working one
I created a simulation where a Rogue Planet enters Solar System and calculates what happens to the Earth's orbit.
import numpy as np 

total_time = 86400*30
dt = 720
position_Rogue = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))
velocity_Rogue = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))
acceleration_Rogue = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))
position_earth = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))
velocity_earth = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))
acceleration_earth = np.zeros((int(total_time / dt), 3))

position_earth[0] = np.array([-8.720402184155567E+07 , -1.249081082441206E+08 , 3.737986027865112E+04]) 
velocity_earth[0] = np.array([2.401992974509115E+01 , -1.707462009431704E+01 ,1.433502989955038E-03]) 

position_Rogue[0] = np.array([9.720402184155567E+07 , -1.549081082441206E+08 , 3.737986027865112E+04]) 
velocity_Rogue[0] = np.array([3.401992974509115E+01 , 1.707462009431704E+01 ,2.433502989955038E-03])
 
G = 6.674e-20
M_SUN= float(1.989 * 10**30)
M_earth = float(5.972 * 10**24)
M_Rogue = float(M_earth*300)#increased from m_earth to30*m_earth .... till 300

for n in range(1, int(total_time/dt)):
    
        acceleration_Rogue[n] = (- G * M_SUN* position_Rogue[n-1]/np.linalg.norm(position_Rogue[n-1])**3- G * M_earth * (position_Rogue[n-1]-position_earth[n-1])/np.linalg.norm(position_Rogue[n-1]-position_earth[n-1]**3)
        
        )
        velocity_Rogue[n] = velocity_Rogue[n-1] + acceleration_Rogue[n-1]*dt
        position_Rogue[n] = position_Rogue[n-1] + velocity_Rogue[n-1]*dt + 0.5*dt**2*acceleration_Rogue[n-1]

        
        acceleration_earth[n] = (
        - G * M_SUN * position_earth[n-1]/np.linalg.norm(position_earth[n-1])**3   
         
        - G * M_Rogue* (position_earth[n-1] - position_Rogue[n-1])/np.linalg.norm(position_earth[n-1] - position_Rogue[n-1])**3
            )

This for loop runs serially, so in every iteration it calculates new positions for objects and in the next iteration it uses the data created from the previous iteration. I want to make this for loop work parallelly so that I can use it in a super-computer. I just need some ideas on how to do that. My goal is to make Total time around 100 years and dt 1 seconds.

Without moving to a quite different algorithm, I don't think this can be parallelized, because it's a recurrence relation.

Have you read about the two-body problem?

@Reinderien I guess I made a small mistake while simplifying the code, unfortunately this case cannot be solved with two body problem equations.

How is this not a two-body problem? It seems fairly textbook.

@Reinderien yeah that's what I thought, but I figured maybe someone knows a way. An idea I have right now is to calculate every body's acceleration parallelly, so that in 1 iteration a few cores could be used.

@Reinderien Well, in the un-simplified version of the code there are 8 different bodies so, unfortunately it wouldn't have any use.

Then this question needs to be edited, because currently it's non-representative of your actual use case. The two-body problem has extremely different computational approaches available than the n-body problem. You need to show a minimum representative problem.

This question is similar to: Vectorized coupled ODE’s for a N body Problem in python. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For running this on a super-computer you need to avoid using Numpy directly. It would be a huge wast of resources. Not to mention Numpy is sequential and multiprocessing would not be efficient anyway (nor certainly multithreading). This is a perfect case for Cython and Numba here due to the the need for efficiency, the large number of iterations on small arrays. C modules also works well though they are more tedious to write. I assume there is no analytical solution to this problem (which is the case for >= 3 bodies in general).

Oh and by the way, supercomputers are mostly large-scale clusters nowadays seen as one unique machine. This means multithreaded code can only use 1 node. Distributed computing is generally required to use more than 1 node. In fact, your code is inherently sequential so it does not matter : you cannot benefit from multiple threads here unless you use a completely different approach. Thus, you should not expect a super-computer to be faster than a good PC. In fact, the later is better here (better energy consumption and flexibility).

Also note that the fact that the computation cannot be parallelized as it is is already stated in comments of your past question. It still applies.
